# Group by class in Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have Product model in my project. And it has product_type as a field. I want only one product from all types of products. I tried doing this,

```
Product.group_by(:product_type).limit(1)
```

This did not work. How can i achieve this?

Comment: try this `Product.all.group_by(&:product_type)` or `Product.all.group_by(&:product_type).limit(1)

Comment: whats is & is used for in &:product_type ?

Comment: `group` would be the query method but you would then have to exclude all other columns what is the desired end result? Is `ProductType` a defined class? Also `*_type` columns have inherent implications in `rails`

Comment: `limit(1)` limits to one result, period, not one result per type. When you say you want one product of each type, you'll need to specify how you're selecting which one. Lowest ID? Alphabetically? Random?

Comment: @tadman exactly....random will do or very first row...I want only one result per type

Comment: what @tadman is trying to tell you is you will not get 1 result per type you will get 1 result all together.

Comment: Is `product_type` a string or an association?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really need is actually:

```
Product.group(:product_type)
```

Let's assume we have data like this:

```
Product.create(name: "TV",     product_type: "Electronics")
Product.create(name: "Diablo", product_type: "Computer Games")
Product.create(name: "Basics", product_type: "Books")

Product.create(name: "Radio",     product_type: "Electronics")
Product.create(name: "Assassins", product_type: "Computer Games")
Product.create(name: "Cooking",   product_type: "Books")
```

When you perform code you've provided it returns single result:

```
result = Product.group(:product_type).limit(1)
result.each { |p| puts "#{p.name} - #{p.product_type}" }
# => Cooking - Books
```

but

```
result = Product.group(:product_type)
result.each { |p| puts "#{p.name} - #{p.product_type}" }
# => Cooking - Books
#    Assassins - Computer Games
#    Radio - Electronics
```

Hope that helps.